# messaging has stopped

Tags: sms

My Mobile  is micromax a46, whenever I am touching the message icon a dialogue box says 'sorry messaging has stopped'. Can't open, read and send messages. Can anybody suggest a solution to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try clearing it's data from application settings (in the settings app). Your messages will probably be deleted, but if you are ready to take that step, it may fix your issue.

Comment: Just to be sure, a backup can be made before this. Some helpers for that task can be found here: [Backup SMS/MMS](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/file_backup#group_133)